# Unhandled exception. StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s)

Tags: .net-core, amazon-eks

1. When I try to connect from Dotnet core to Redis server in EKS pods I have got this error if anyone has solutions so please Help me.
2. I have 2 pods one is for Redis cache and I deploy using Official Docker images and the second one is my dotnet core application where I store my login session.